# Extract numbers from a string list - python

Tags: python, list-comprehension

If I have a list like this `[ [100], [500], [300] ]`, what's the best way in python to extract the numbers from it?

```
result = [ 100, 500, 300 ]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/952914/589206):

```
l=[[100], [500], [300]]
result=[item for sublist in l for item in sublist]
```

From [wikibooks](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Python_Programming/Tips_and_Tricks):

```
def flatten(seq, list = None):
    """flatten(seq, list = None) -> list

    Return a flat version of the iterator `seq` appended to `list`
    """
    if list == None:
        list = []
    try:                          # Can `seq` be iterated over?
        for item in seq:          # If so then iterate over `seq`
            flatten(item, list)      # and make the same check on each item.
    except TypeError:             # If seq isn't iterable
        list.append(seq)             # append it to the new list.
    return list
```

Google is your friend ...

Comment: well, I did it like that:
result = [ i[1:len(i)-1] for i in l]
thanks :)

Answer (score 3):

```
x = [ [100] , [500] , [300] ]
y = [ i[0] for i in x]

#or
from itertools import chain
y = list(chain.from_iterable(x))
```

Comment: Or (equivalent to the first) `import operator; y = map(operator.itemgetter(0), x)` :-)